# XSD : Workaround to Unique Particle Attribution

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have this schema that triggers Unique Particle Attribution violation. I do understand why, but I don't see any other way to express it. The schema is :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Element" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:attribute name="First" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="SomeAttribute" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:attribute name="Second" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="SomeOtherAttribute" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and the XML it should validate :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Element First="true" SomeAttribute="abc"/>
    <Element Second="true" SomeOtherAttribute="def"/>
</Root>
```

I don't want to simplify the schema, meaning I don't want to make any of the attributes optionnal, or allow a mix between attributes... Also I can't change the name of "Element" to something like "FirstElement", "SecondElement".
Is there a way around this in XSD ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you feel reluctant to switch to RNG entirely, you could probably augment an XSD similar to the one you posted (with a single `Element` and optional attributes) via [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) asserts. That would count as another alternative I suppose. A non-XSD solution either way but perhaps less painful this way if you are already using XSLT...

Comment: @emma very minor point to help anyone cut-and-pasting your schema: you left off the `</xs:schema>` close tag. Don't worry, I've edited it for you. *EDIT* actually I see now the end tag was there, but wasn't visible due to formatting (it wasn't indented).

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. My conclusion is that it is actually not possible to do that in XSD 1.0. Some leads would be Schematron, XSD 1.1, or RNG.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the schema is you have given the element twice both times with different attributes. This isn't allowable in XSD.

Conceptually the reason XSD works in this manner is you are supposed to be giving elements with a type, but you have two non compatible types to the same element.

For example:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="FirstElement" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xs:attribute name="First" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="SomeAttribute" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="SecondElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xs:attribute name="Second" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="SomeOtherAttribute" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This should allow the XML to validate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <FirstElement First="true" SomeAttribute="abc"/>
    <SecondElement Second="true" SomeOtherAttribute="def"/>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know why it triggers this error, and that your solution would solve it, but I should have mentionned also that I don't want to change the name "Element", they have to remain the same.

Comment: @emma I don't think its possible to work the way you want it to. Is it possible to validate in another layer?

Comment: What do you mean, another layer ?

Comment: Where your processing the xml document rather than in the communication definition.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I think we are rather going to produce an RNG schema rather than XSD, because RNG works fine with definitions like these.

Comment: @Wes actually, the rule that an element with the same name can't have different declarations (such as different attributes) only applies to top-level elements - it's OK for local elements (declared within a complex type or a group), like `<Element>` in the question.  It's global vs. local symbol space http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#GlobalvsLocal - see the `<title>` discussion at the end of that section. (The problem with the schema in the SO question is the UPA rule, which can be overcome by changing "unbounded" to "1" - the attributes aren't a problem).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in XSD 1.1 using conditional type assignment. XSD 1.1 is currently supported in Saxon and Xerces.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the lead. Since we already have worked with RNG, I think we will go this way first, but good to know.

Comment: Conditional type assignment would certainly make it possible to have either a `First` attribute or a `Second` but not both.  But by itself it will not achieve the property in the OP's existing schema of ensuring that all instances of `First` come before any instances of `Second`.  For that, assertions are likely to be needed.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do *exactly* what you want; the best you can do is accept a trade-off.  For example, it would work if the first `<Element>` occurred a fixed number of times (not variable) - which isn't what you want.

Just to illustrate:

```
$ cat upa.xsd
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Element" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">  <!-- CHANGE -->
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:attribute name="First" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="SomeAttribute" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:attribute name="Second" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="SomeOtherAttribute" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

$ cat upa.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Element First="true" SomeAttribute="abc"/>
    <Element Second="true" SomeOtherAttribute="def"/>
</Root>

$ xmllint --schema upa.xsd upa.xml --noout
upa.xml validates
```

Comment: Yes, I can not know in advance the number of times first Element will appear. Thanks anyway for the response, confirming that this is not possible in XSD.

Answer (score 0):

For some people the solution could be very simple:

Make sure all elements with the same name, which are siblings, use the same attributes.

For example change this:

```
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="widget-wrap"/>
<g:FlowPanel styleName="widget-wrap"/>
```

To this:

```
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="widget-wrap"/>
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="widget-wrap"/>
```